# async/await swift 5.5 on X86_64 linux

Tags: swift, linux, async-await, x86-64

I'm use swift 5.5.2 for linux service.

And decided start using async/await for linux service, but  async/await is not supported.

I need use something like this?

```
if #available(macOS 10.15, iOS 13.0, watchOS 6.0, tvOS 13.0, *) {
    Task(priority: .utility){
        //do something
    }
} else {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .utility).async{
        //do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest you defer the adoption of Swift concurrency (async-await) until it is available on your platform. It will be a frustrating experience to try to write good `async`-`await` code without compiler support, having a rich library of framework API that support `async`-`await`, the ability to experiment and test your attempts, etc.

Besides, while a deep understanding of GCD will be useful when you dive into `async`-`await`, you should dispel notions of one-for-one replacements for your existing GCD API. The new Swift concurrency employs completely different patterns than you would see in GCD. E.g., the most compelling use-case is to replace towers of nested GCD completion handler closures with more natural `async`-`await` flow.

Also, let us consider your example: `Task { ... }` and `DispatchQueue.global() { ... }` solve different problems. The former is for “I have some Swift concurrency `async` code that I wish to start in its own `Task` (e.g., perhaps launching it from a non-asynchronous calling point)” and the latter is for “I have something slow/blocking that I need to get off the main queue.” They are two completely different propositions. If anything, IMHO, `Task.detached { ... }` is a closer analog to the old “dispatch something slow to a global queue” pattern.

Bottom line, the new Swift concurrency is not just a new surface layer replacement for GCD with one-for-one equivalency at the API level. You would be best served to learn it on a platform with Swift concurrency support (or defer such an exercise until you have access to it on your platform).

I might suggest watching WWDC 2021 video [Swift concurrency: Update a sample app](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10194/). While this focuses on a different platform (iOS), it gives you a good sense of how one goes about refactoring GCD code to the new Swift concurrency. A bunch of `if #available(...)`-`else` statements is unlikely to be the approach you will want to take.